# python sort objects by difference in attributes/weights

Tags: python-2.7, sorting

Is there a good way to do this sort function in python?

The array holds objects where each one has a weight value.

I'd appreciate something like [Javascript sort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8ttX.png).

I tried doing `cmp` but run into this error:

> TypeError: comparison function must return int, not float

Answer (score 1):

Use python's built in `sorted` function with a `lambda`, and cast the result as an integer.

`sorted_list = sorted(unsorted_iterable, lambda x, y: int(x.weight - y.weight))`

Comment: This will not work. Casting the value to `int` will truncate both `0.5` and `-0.5` to `0`, causing the sort to treat `x` and `y` as equal if the difference in their weights is less than `1`. You could consider using the built-in `cmp` function to use the default comparison on floats, but the most appropriate solution uses `sorted`'s keyword argument `key`. [(See docs.)](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#sorted)